# Fixed top image + vertically repeating remainder

Tags: css, background-image

I'm designing a webpage that has an image of paper as the background for the content area. The body will have it's own background image. The paper needs to start below the top of the page and repeat all the way to the bottom, no matter the length.

Here's the problem:

I need to have the top of the paper at the top of the div, and then the repeating part of the paper below it repeating vertically down the page, creating the illusion on one giant piece of paper with a normal top. I need to have this happen in one div (ideally), because I can't split the content. I've been combing the web, specifically CSS3 sites. I know you can have multiple background images per div, etc., but I don't think you can specify a pixel position where the second repeating image starts. I created the seamless, vertically repeating image already in Photoshop.

BTW, I am willing to throw IE eight and below under the bus if necessary.

If I haven't given you a "visual" by now, imagine this. You tear out a piece of paper from a note book, the top of the paper is at the top of the page, but you never see the bottom. As the page gets longer, you just see more and more of the center of the page.

Thanks.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(body-background.gif) repeat scroll left top;
}

.paper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1170px;
    background: url(paper-top.png) left top no-repeat, url(paper-bottom.png) left 100px repeat-y;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="paper">
    <!--content here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The background in the "paper" class what I would like to write (may need to scroll to see it). E.g.: start 100px from the start of the page and repeat vertically.

*EDIT*

Got it working with Peter's help. I don't know if's going to cause problems with positioning inside the content div and come back to haunt me. But it works, as is, now. Thanks, Peter.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbzzc/)

If all hell breaks looks, I'll have to go with the two divs and split the logo, or give it some positioning...

Comment: could you provide some (simplified) code? Perhaps even a jsfiddle?

Comment: @PeterVR I added some phony code.

Comment: Why not have two `div` elements? One for the "top" of the paper, and the other for the repeating paper background? Then, you don't have to fuss with any specific CSS3 foolishness, or JavaScript trickery, or whatever.

Comment: @JonahBishop I hear ya. I wanted to avoid it at all costs, though. Because the alternative is not any prettier. I'll have to cut the logo  in two pieces among over things. I'll end up with a frankenstein page, instead of something that should be simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on not splitting up the content, i would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ntWTE/

I did not use the css3 multiple background option, as I am used to making cross browser sites, and support is still pour. I just added two divs to contain the different background images, and positioned them absolute behind the content. Perhaps not the most pretty solution, but it should work fine in all browsers.

```
.paper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 450px;
    position: relative;
}
.paper-bg {
    background: #cff;    /* the repeating image for the paper */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.paper-bg-top {
    position: absolute;   
    background: #ccf;  /* the top image for the paper */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100%;    
}
.paper-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;    
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. I'm in bed on my ipad right now, but I'll give you the checkmark tomorrow if it works. Thanks for your time, Peter...and everyone else as well :)